# When to load default content on a Master Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, code-behind

I have the following placeholder in my main master page.  I would like to not have to duplicate my news content in several content pages, so I choose to simply not provide this content in them, and the master page should provide its default.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SideBarContent" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="newsGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

When I try the following code, I get an error because newsGrid is null.  I assume I'm doing this at the wrong place in the page lifecycle, but I don't know where the right place is.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Header.DataBind();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        newsGrid.DataSource = _newsService.ListActive();
        newsGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code behind you're showing here on one of your pages, or on the masterpage itself? I'm assuming the former, but won't answer in case I'm wrong.

Comment: @martin, everything is from the master page.

Comment: Are you sure a user control might not be a better solution for this?

Comment: @Andrew, a user control would indeed be a better solution, but I still want to have the news column present even if a content page doesn't use that control.  Unless I don't fully understand you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content between within your ContentPlaceHolder will be replaced by the content provided by the content page.

So, when your content page has a Content control that targets the SideBarContent placeholder your newsGrid will be replaced.

With this in mind, are you seeing this issue on all pages, or just pages that replace the content? I would expect this to be null for any page where you replace the content in a content page.

*update*

I've just quickly tried this.

With a page that doesn't define an `asp:Content` control that targets the `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` the controls inside that `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` will be available to you in the code behind.

In a page where it DOES define an `asp:Content` targetting this `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` then the controls inside that `asp:ConentPlaceHolder` are removed and, therefore, null when accessed in the code behind.

So, this content within the placeholder on the masterpage will be replaced when a content page provides content, and so your master page must be coded to expect this situation.

So, if you have this in the Site.master:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="OtherContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="foo" runat="server" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

... then in Page1.aspx you have this...

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="OtherContent">
</asp:Content>
```

... then the button "foo" will be null for that page. If, you omit this Content control is Page2.aspx, the button foo will be instantiated and available in your masterpage code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this will be null for pages that
    // remove the default content of "OtherContent"
    var foo = this.foo;
}
```

So, I suspect you simply need to guard against this grid being null and if it is you can assume the content page has provided it's own news list.